How to use one namespace into an another namespace in same solution?
I'm facing one issue . How to use one namespace into an another namespace in same solution?
I'm attached the code for your reference.
using namespace Dapper
{


    namespace DapperTest.Repositories
    {
        internal class ProductRepositoryTests
        {
            private Mock<IDbConnection> _mockDbConnection;
            private Mock<DapperrContext> _mockContext;
            private ProductRepository _repository;
        }
    }
}

Thanks In Advance
I'm excepting how to solve this error

Could you share more detail about your project as you mentioned you encountered an error but I did not see any error messages?

It's unclear exactly what you are trying to do and what the problem is. That said, this using namespace syntax is not one that I am familiar with. I suspect you need to change it to the following instead:
using Dapper;

namespace DapperTest.Repositories
{
    internal class ProductRepositoryTests
    {
        private Mock<IDbConnection> _mockDbConnection;
        private Mock<DapperContext> _mockContext;
        private ProductRepository _repository;
    }
}

If this does not answer your question, please update your question with more details about what you are trying to do and the specific error message.
